# How to make an ansible playbook that works according to user input?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

In my ansible playbook i am taking 2 inputs from user and i also wanted to take a third input which should be optional at times and if user provides the value for var3 then playbook must execute a task otherwise it should not, so what is the way to achieve this?

Also i wanted to know that i am using awx open-source UI for ansible so i choose the hosts to run the playbook in ansible awx inventory, after that what should i write in 'hosts' of my playbook or it can be left alone.

```
 - name: Updating "{{ service_name  }}" server codebase and starting its service.
   hosts: all
   tasks:
    - name: Stopping nginx service
      command: sudo service nginx stop


    - name: Performing git checkout in the specified directory "{{ path  }}"
      command: git checkout .
      args:
        chdir: "{{ path }}"

    - name: Running npm install in the directory "{{ path }}"
      command: npm install
      args:
        chdir: "{{ path }}/node_modules"


    - name: Restarting the "{{ service_name }}" service
      command: sudo service "{{ service_name }}" restart

    - name: Restarting the nginx service
      command: sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Who is the user in this instance? you? if you are the user then you can run

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts <your-playbook> -e "service_name=<yourservice>"
```

to dynamically change the service_name variable upon playbook excecution.

you can then add the second variable to the command also, but be aware with the 'optional' third variable as i'm sure if you do not reference all variables in your playbook you will get an error.

EDIT: You will need to ref both service_name and path variables when you execute the ansible-playbook command, where is the 3rd variable as it doesnt appear to be in your provided code sample?